# Z-Transform of a Restricted Function

Tags: z-transform

$H[n]=(1/2)^n (u[n+9]-u[n-10])$ I want to find the z-transform and its zeros and poles. But when I try to do that there will be high power of z's. It is between -9 and 10 (There are 20 terms.). So, I cannot find its zeros and poles. What should I do?

Comment: By the way, I should do it by hand. Not with MATLAB or anything else.

Comment: By z transform, do you mean $\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_n z^{-n}$? Is $u$ meant to be a unit step at 0?

Comment: Yes, I meant that @copper.hat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using the bilateral z transform. Then
(since $u(k+9)-u(k-10)$ is 1 for $ |k|\le 9$ and zero otherwise) we have
$\hat{H}(z) = {\cal Z}(H)(z) =\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty {1 \over 2^k}(u(k+9)-u(k-10))z^{-k}  =\sum_{k=-9}^9 {1 \over 2^k} z^{-k} $.

For $z \neq {1 \over 2}$, we can sum the geometric series to get
$\hat{H}(z) = {1 \over {1\over 2^{9}}z^{-9}}{ 1-{1\over 2^{19}}z^{-19}\over 1-{1\over 2}z^{-1} }$.

Comment: Sorry to to say that but $k$ must be -infinity to infinity. I did not see that when you asked.

Comment: Well, in that case you just need to add the terms corresponding to $k=-9,...,-1$.

Comment: But when I do that I cannot find a simple solution like you did. I find 20 terms in the numerator.

Comment: Same idea, different starting point.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see that.